# Adding a parent in JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns as below:

```
Column1 Column2
122132  123123
213213  231233
231234  232133
```

I have converted this to json using the below code:

```
df_json = dataframe.to_json(orient='records')
```

OUTPUT JSON:

```
[{"Column1":"122132","Column2":"123123"},{"Column1":"213213","Column2":"231233"},{"Column1":"231234","Column2":"232133"}]
```

I need to add a parent to it so that the JSON looks like below:

```
{
"APP_Request":
[{"Column1":"122132","Column2":"123123"},{"Column1":"213213","Column2":"231233"},{"Column1":"231234","Column2":"232133"}]
}
```

How do I do this?

I tried the below but the JSON is not in the right format.

```
df_new = dict()
df_new["SFDC_Request"] = df_json
```

The OUTPUT of the above is below and is not the right format:

```
{'APP_Request': '[{"Column1":"122132","Column2":"123123"},{"Column1":"213213","Column2":"231233"},{"Column1":"231234","Column2":"232133"}]'}
```

The above json has single quote and square brackets inside the single quote which is a miss from the what I want to do. Is there a way to create the JSON in the format I need?

Comment: new_dict = {"APP_Request": df_json}

Comment: This still adds the single quotes after semi-colon of 'APP_Request'.                                                                                                                                  {'APP_Request': '[{"Column1":"122132","Column2":"123123"},{"Column1":"213213","Column2":"231233"},{"Column1":"231234","Column2":"232133"}]'}

Comment: Then your df_json is a string and not a json dict. You can convert a string with json.loads(df_json)

Comment: Thanks this worked. I converted the dataframe to json using pandas.to_json(dataframe). Does this not create a json by default?

Comment: Mace, will you please close this question by answering. I am not sure how to close this question and I am assuming you will close this. Please let me know if I need to do this.

Comment: I have answered it.About pandas to_json it does return a string. See  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to create a parent, a creating a new dict:

```
new_dict = {"APP_Request": df_json}
```

Because your df_json is a string you need to convert it to real json with json.loads().

So

```
new_dict = {"APP_Request": json.loads(df_json)}
```

Comment: I inspired your deleted answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65138856/2901002 ;) so thank you.