# Converting timestamp column in custom string format to seconds in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns containing timestamp values in string format. The values are like '0D_0H_1M_35S_0MS'. I would like to convert all these column values into milliseconds

[image]

Comment: Don't paste screenshots. Share data that that be copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replace string to format for possible convert to timedeltas by [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and multiple by `1000` for miliseconds per columns in custom function in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
cols = ['date','date1']

def parse(x):
    s =  x.replace({'D_':' Days ','H_':':','M_':':','S_':'.','MS':''}, regex=True)
    return pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds().mul(1000).astype(int)
    
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(parse)
print (df)
     date   date1
0   95000   95000
1  155000  155000
```

If format is never change is possible extract digits by [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), convert to integers and multiple by unit Series, last sum values.

Solution is inspired by deleted answer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['0D_0H_1M_35S_0MS','0D_0H_2M_35S_0MS'],
                   'date1':['0D_0H_1M_35S_0MS','0D_0H_2M_35S_0MS']})

cols = ['date','date1']

def parse(x):
    a = pd.Series([86400000, 3600000, 60000, 1000, 1])
    return x.str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].unstack().astype(int).mul(a).sum(axis=1)
    
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(parse)

print (df)
     date   date1
0   95000   95000
1  155000  155000
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for individual columns. Can you help me do this in a single shot for all such columns?